# Segue to chat viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, segue

I have included images to hopefully make this easier to understand. My FirstViewController has a collection view with a list of users from my firebase database.When I click on the users I am segued to a DetailedViewController that has more information about the user that was clicked. Within that viewController, the goal is to click on the compose button and segue to a viewController that allows me to chat with the user, whose profile I clicked on. [image]

I have gotten as far as this for segueing from DetailedViewController to  Message user 1.

```
@IBAction func SendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "chat", sender: self)

}
```

I am not sure how to make sure I am sending the particular user I click on a message.

This is how I am passing data from FirstViewController to DetailedViewController.

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "details" {

            if let indexPaths = self.CollectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems{

                let vc = segue.destination as! BookDetailsViewController
                let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.CollectionView!.indexPath(for: cell)
                let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let Booked = post["title"] as? String
                vc.Booked = Booked


                print(indexPath?.row)

            }  }
```

Comment: You mean from detailedViewController to chatViewController or you haven't passed the data from firstViewController to detailedViewController ?

Comment: @NiravD the data has been passed from FirstViewController to DetailedViewController, my issue is when I click the compose button in the DetailedViewController, I want to be able to send a message to the user I clicked on

Comment: Have you passed the users detailed to chatViewController also, so that you are having detail on chatViewController to chat with specific user?

Comment: @NiravD I'm not sure how to, that is the question I am asking

Comment: yes I am @NiravD

Comment: What i'm asking **How you are passing data from firstViewController to DetailedViewController?** I get that you are passing data from firstController to detailedViewController I'm asking how you are achieving that same goes for chatViewController

Comment: Try below answer by @moni15 if it not works for you inform here will post one for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One route to take is in your `DetailViewController` class, or whatever class you have implementing `performSegue(withIdentifier:, sender:)`, add this:

```
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "chat", let dest = segue.destination as? ChatViewController else {
        return
    }

    dest.user = self.user

}
```

I don't know how you have the **user** declared but if **user** is an object, do what I have above. If you're saying **user** as a way to umbrella multiple properties you want to pass.. do this:

```
dest.name = self.name
dest.number = self.number  
//etc
```

`prepare(for segue:, sender:)` allows you to intercept any segue from it's class and set up whatever variables needed before the `performSegue(`...`)` executes. To target your code to a specific `segue`/destination/situation, make sure your code runs a check on those constraints before executing; otherwise the code will execute on all `segue`s implemented in the class. In my example, I used your `segue`'s `identifier` as that check.